# Use momentary switch to switch between three devices

Tags: switches, relay

I need a solution to use one momentary switch to switch between modes on a pump. Off (NC) | Low | High. What I mean is you push the pushbutton once to turns pump on low, push it again for high and again for off (NC).  Additionally on low I'd really like the switch light to flash slow, and on high the switch light to flash fast. I've seen it done with Raspberry pi (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOwnG5Vhzcs) but would like a simpler (maybe relay) option.

Comment: PIC10LF322 in SOT-23-6.

Comment: Using a microcontroller is the simpler option but overall probably not by much.

Comment: you said nothing about the pump ... how would the speed change be accomplished?

Comment: Could be done with some relay logic, but LED indicators  complicate the task. It needs DC power supply. In that case using microcontroller make the task easier.

Comment: Although you've stated your goal, you've forgotten to actually ask a question in your "question"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a MCU even, simple 74HC logic would work just fine.

- De-bounce the switch with RC filter. Normally open, ie press switch=voltage comes through.
- Give it as input to a decade counter IC like 74HC4017. Ouput pin 0=off, 1=low, 2=high, 3= wire to chip select of the IC, use a BJT or similar to inverse polarity of the signal.
- Add some driver IC or MOSFET to the outputs, then let these drive 5V coil relays. Flyback diode across the coil.
- Decoupling caps and TVS on the usual appropriate places.
- For blinking lights you can use LEDs with built-in flashing logic. Supply these from the relay outputs.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much guys. That helped awesomely. I'm going to get a pcb board made up with the inner workings (including a decade counter IC) on low voltage and  then send the power to bigger relays to run the pumps. Should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one, using two magnetic latch relays K1 & K2, three momentary push button switches S1, S2 & S3 and a diode matrix.

[image]

Freewheeling diodes and LEDs are not shown.

Using two LEDs to indicate 'Low' and 'High', instead of a single LED blinking at two frequencies, would keep the circuit quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

Your did not really explain what you want to do, but based on title (switching between three devices), perhaps simpler solution without complete DIY circuit might be to use ready-made microcontroller device such as [Shelly](https://shelly.cloud/products/shelly-25-smart-home-automation-relay/) or [Sonoff](https://www.itead.cc/smart-home/sonoff-4ch-r3-pro-r3.html). I know for fact that Shelly can be configured to control two devices with one momentary switch. This assumes that you control your motor speed with two separate On/Off switches and not via PWM or any other type of regulation.

As for light, it is really not clear what you want, however shelly again can trigger web request when something happens (e.g. switch is pressed), you could use it to change the light (via other shelly, or even simpler controller).

Answer (score 0):

These days, the simplest solution to almost any non-trivial logic control problem is a small microcontroller.  For a one-off prototype, look at something off-the-shelf, such an Arduino.  For mass production there are many tiny little microcontrollers available at low cost.

Anything electro-mechanical with relays, solenoids and switches is going to end up bigger and more expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Many cheap Chinese rechargeable lithium ion battery torchlight and fan use 1 momentary switch and 6 or 8 pin ic( e.g LP78070) . 1 momentary switch is pressed repeatedly gives low, medium, high and off modes(fan) or high, low, flashing and off modes(torchlight). Some of the torchlight are cheap($2). The pc board of those torchlight or portable fan can be used. The output from the ic (wire going to the load(LED or fan motor) can be connected to mosfet or bjt of appropriate amperage/voltage(i.e amplified) to meet the motor need. The modes(off, low, medium and high speed) of the motor speed can be achieved by pressing 1 button repeatedly.
Oscilloscope and dmm can be used to view or measure waveform/voltage of each mode to see difference(frequency or voltage)
In one of the fan I checked, at off =0v, low speed=3.5v, medium speed=4.4v, high speed=5.9v. This can be connected to the gate of a mosfet(low Vgate threshold type) to switch high current